# Doubt in differential of Gauss Map

Tags: differential-geometry, differential

This might be a trivial doubt. It is from the book "do Carmo Differential Geometry of Curves and surfaces"

[image: Gauss map definition]

[image: Figure]
Here, it is mentioned that "the tangent vector $N'(0) = dN_p(\alpha '(0))$is a vector in $T_p(S)$".
 How is that? I would like a geometric as well as mathematical answer.

Later, the author writes the following  -

[image]

How is $dN_p(x_uu'(0) + x_vv'(0)) = \frac d{dt} N(u(t), v(t))|_{t=0}$?

Comment: The first question should be addressed by Figure 3.3, does it not clarify your doubt? Which book are you reading?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I am reading do Carmo differential geometry book, and no, I can't understand from the figure 3.3 which I have attached now

Comment: I think I understand my second question now , whose solution I found here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641662/is-this-an-abuse-of-notation?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found yourself, the answer to your second question is that the author abuse notation. The same goes for your first question. It is rather $(N\circ\alpha)'(0) = dN_p(\alpha '(0))$, which follows from definition.

As for the answer to your first question, note that $dN_p$ has codomain $T_p(S)$ and so $dN_p(\alpha '(0))\in T_p(S)$.

Comment: I think that this does not answer the first question. How can you say that $dN_p$ has codomain $T_pS?$ That is not obvious, because $N\colon S\to \mathbb S^2$, therefore $dN_p$ is naturally a linear map $$dN_p\colon T_pS \to T_{N(p)} \mathbb S^2.$$ You need some argument to identify $T_{N(p)}\mathbb S^2$ with $T_p S$. The text only says that "they are parallel planes", and the way I see it, the content of john doe's question is precisely "how is this identification performed?"

Answer (score 2):

The analytical explanation of the first fact is simply that, since 
$$
N(t)\cdot N(t)=1,\quad \forall t, $$ 
then differentiating this relation you obtain 
$$
\frac{ dN}{dt}\cdot N=0.$$ 
Here $N(t)$ is the restriction of the normal field $N$ to the curve $\alpha=\alpha(t)\in S$.